# pymongo MongoClient Takes Forever To Close

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am running an Apache server that can execute python files. To get the data from the python file it has to finish executing.

These 3 lines of code take 600 milliseconds! Absolutely unacceptable for webpages

The thing is it prints the data I need almost instantly.. And then takes 600 milliseconds to close (That was with more than these 3 lines of code obviously)

I ran it with "time python3 file.py" outside of Apache to get the time

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from pymongo import MongoClient
Client = MongoClient()
```

Not sure if theres some code I can use to forcefully close the connection and use whats already been printed so the script can continue. Any tricks / hacky things you can think of are welcome lol

Comment: Typically web applications will use a pool of connections (which have already been established). When a web request needs to make a db request, it'll take a connection from the pool, make the request using that connection, and then put it back in the pool when the web request completes.

Comment: Also consider that the 600 ms includes python's startup time. On my machine it takes between 50-100ms to start. I imagine the import also takes a reasonable amount of time since it does disk I/O.

Comment: The import takes 40ms. Just printing something in python takes 10ms "time python3 file.py" file.py = print('hi')

Comment: Replace `#!/usr/bin/python3` to `#!/usr/bin/python`, your system use `2.X` and you use `3.x` or wait until `3.X` versions are default.  I think you've mixed the `newest` and `stable` terms (your hardware and database configuration has been ignored).